# What is the difference between *(pointer) and (*pointer)?

Tags: c++, pointers

Please see the following block of code. Can you tell me the difference between `*(sample)` and `(*sample)`?

```
for(i = 0; i < num_samples ; i++ ) 
    {
        *(sample) &= 0xfff ;
        
        if( (*sample) & 0x800 ) 
            *(sample) |= 0xf000 ;
            *(sample+1) &= 0xfff ;
            
        if( *(sample+1) & 0x800 ) 
            *(sample+1) |= 0xf000 ;
            
        fprintf( my_data->fout, "%d, %d\n", *sample, *(sample+1) );
        
        sample += 2 ;
    }
```

Comment: The only difference is when operator precedence would give you an unintuitive result. `*` has higher precedence than the binary operators, so for you example, there is no difference. Something like `*(a)++` and `(*a)++` does have a difference, however. [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @AndersK the problem is that they see both patterns in their code, they can't observe any obvious difference, and they want to know what (if anything) they're missing.

Comment: Please note that the indentation of this code is misleading. Look at the second statement *after* the first `if`, is it clear to you that `*(sample+1) &= 0xfff ;` is executed regardless of `(*sample) & 0x800` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is purely a question about operator precedence

`*sample` , `*(sample)` and `(*sample)` all do this same thing in isolation. They `deference` the 'sample' pointer

Things get more interesting when combined with other operators. You have an example

```
 *(sample+1)
```

Lets take out the parens

```
  *sample+1
```

This could mean two things

- Give me the value pointed at by sample and add 1 to it
- give me the value thats one after where sample points

Explictly bracketing that gives

- (*sample) + 1 => do the deref, then add 1
- *(sample+1)   => add 1 then deref

So what does

```
*sample+1
```

mean (ie with no brackets to dictate the order), not surprisingly it means

```
(*sample) + 1
```

you can apply the same logic to all your other combinatons